# Manager Attribute in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, attributes

I want to manager the `Attribute` easier, so I'm finding the way control all `Attribute`.
Currently, each function in controller I registration one or many `Attribute`. 
Ex:

```
[MaintenanceModeDenyAttribute]  
public ActionResult SaveGenericObject(GenericSaveObject saveObject)  {  }
```

---

```
[MaintenanceModeDenyAttribute("New student")]
public ActionResult ReturnGraduates() { }
```

How do manager all `Attribute` in a class, they can be applied for many functions of controller?
When app start, `Attribute` class can registration.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply attribute at controller level if its usage is permitted or you can also add it into Global Filters collection in global.asax.cs for whole application as below.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new MaintenanceModeDenyAttribute());            
}
```